# In R tidymodels how can I specify contrasts for specific variables?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I would like to specify "sum to zero" contrasts for two predictors in a LM using a `tidymodels` recipe.  Is it possible?  In looking at the `recipes` documentation, before 1.3, it seems there were attempts to build the variable specific options but the strategy was shifted to a global option.

I am trying to convert this base R code into `tidymodels`:

```r
Bikeshare <- ISLR2::Bikeshare  # start with original data
contrasts(Bikeshare$hr) <- contr.sum(24)
contrasts(Bikeshare$mnth) <- contr.sum(12)
mod.lm2 <-
  lm(
    bikers ~ mnth + hr + workingday + temp + weathersit,
    data = Bikeshare
  )
summary(mod.lm2)
```

I got this far:

```r
library(tidymodels)
Bikeshare <- ISLR2::Bikeshare  # start with original data
contrasts(Bikeshare$hr) <- contr.sum(24)
contrasts(Bikeshare$mnth) <- contr.sum(12)

lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

the_rec <- 
  recipe(
    bikers ~ mnth + hr + workingday + temp + weathersit,
    data = Bikeshare
  ) %>%
  step_dummy(c(mnth, hr), one_hot = TRUE)

the_workflow<- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_rec) %>% 
  add_model(lm_spec)

the_workflow_fit_lm_fit <- 
  fit(the_workflow, data = Bikeshare) %>% 
  extract_fit_parsnip()

summary(the_workflow_fit_lm_fit$fit)
```

Does anybody know how to get the same results out of a `tidymodels` workflow?

I don't think I can use contr.sum as a global option.  This gives me the betas I would like for two of the variables but it changes the contrasts on others.

```
BikeShare <- ISLR2::Bikeshare # be sure to work with original data ; 
old_opt <- options()$contrast; 
options(contrasts = c('contr.sum', 'contr.poly'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for `step_dummy()` have :

> To change the type of contrast being used, change the global contrast option via `options`.

so there is no way, outside of global options, to change it.

We should probably have an example though :-/

Note that, for new samples, the options are read from the global option again. Make sure that they are set the same at prediction-time:

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
tidymodels_prefer()

data("penguins")

penguins <- 
  penguins %>% 
  distinct(species)

# R's defaults
old_opt <- options()$contrast
old_opt
#>         unordered           ordered 
#> "contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"

# default contrast
default <- 
  recipe(~ species, data = penguins) %>% 
  step_dummy(species) %>% 
  prep()

default %>%  bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   species_Chinstrap species_Gentoo
#>               <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1                 0              0
#> 2                 0              1
#> 3                 1              0

# Do do something different

# Now set to something else:
options(contrasts = c('contr.sum', 'contr.poly'))

with_opt <- 
  recipe(~ species, data = penguins) %>% 
  step_dummy(species) %>% 
  prep()

with_opt %>% bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   species_X1 species_X2
#>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1          1          0
#> 2         -1         -1
#> 3          0          1

# reset options: 

options(contrasts = old_opt)
with_opt %>% bake(new_data = penguins)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   species_Chinstrap species_Gentoo
#>               <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1                 0              0
#> 2                 0              1
#> 3                 1              0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

edit for clarity